# I'm trying to make a simple change of background color but it's not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a simple game using pygame and I'm trying to change the background color, the following code is what I'm trying to do:

```
self.mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.mouse_click:
        if (self.screenSize[0]/2 < self.mouse_position[0] < self.screenSize[0]/2 + 40) and \
                (self.screenSize[1]/2 < self.mouse_position[1] < self.screenSize[1]/2 + 40):
            with open("settings.txt", "wb") as settings:
                if self.background_color != [255, 0, 0]:
                    self.color = [255, 0, 0]
                    pickle.dump(self.color, settings)
                elif self.background_color != [0, 0, 0]:
                    self.color = [0, 0, 0]
                    pickle.dump(self.color, settings)
```

the first time that I click it works, but after this the color doesn't change anymore, could anyone help me with this?

the self.color variable is what I'm using as the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be that you have self.background_color being evaluated in your if/elif statements, then you are changing self.color. When self.background_color is evaluated the second time, it still contains the original color.

Comment: thank you, it was a simple mistake but I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

Make it so that one color corresponds to one button and another color corresponds to another button